# How to add spacing between two rows of multiple divs each

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to add a space between the upper row of 4 divs and the lower row of 4 divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- freshdesignweb top bar -->
        <div class="freshdesignweb-top">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a>
            <span class="right">
                <a href="#">
                    <strong>Back to the freshdesignweb Article</strong>
                </a>
            </span>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div><!--/ freshdesignweb top bar -->
        <header>
            <h1><span>Tutorials</span>Demo CSS Table Price Hosting Plan</h1>
        </header>       
 <!-- start header here-->
<header>
<div id="fdw-pricing-table">
<div class="plan plan1">
    <div class="header">Enterprise</div>
    <div class="price">$59</div>  
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>      
    <ul>
        <li><b>10GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>100GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>20</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>         
</div>
<div class="plan plan2">
    <div class="header">Professional</div>
    <div class="price">$29</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>  
    <ul>
        <li><b>5GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>50GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>10</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>            
</div>
<div class="plan plan3">
    <div class="header">Standard</div>
    <div class="price">$19</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>
    <ul>
        <li><b>3GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>25GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>5</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>        
</div>
<div class="plan plan4">
    <div class="header">Basic</div>
    <div class="price">$9</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>
    <ul>
        <li><b>1GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>10GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>2</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>        
</div>
<div class="plan plan1">
    <div class="header">Enterprise</div>
    <div class="price">$59</div>  
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>      
    <ul>
        <li><b>10GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>100GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>20</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>         
</div>
<div class="plan plan2">
    <div class="header">Professional</div>
    <div class="price">$29</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>  
    <ul>
        <li><b>5GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>50GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>10</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>            
</div>
<div class="plan plan3">
    <div class="header">Standard</div>
    <div class="price">$19</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>
    <ul>
        <li><b>3GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>25GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>5</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>        
</div>
<div class="plan plan4">
    <div class="header">Basic</div>
    <div class="price">$9</div>
    <div class="monthly">per month</div>
    <ul>
        <li><b>1GB</b> Disk Space</li>
        <li><b>10GB</b> Monthly Bandwidth</li>
        <li><b>2</b> Email Accounts</li>
        <li><b>Unlimited</b> subdomains</li>            
    </ul>
    <a class="signup" href="#">Sign up</a>        
</div>  
</div>
</header><!-- end header -->

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fdw-pricing-table {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 928px; /* total computed width */
    zoom: 1;
}

#fdw-pricing-table:before, #fdw-pricing-table:after {
  content: "";
  display: table
}

#fdw-pricing-table:after {
  clear: both
}

/* --------------- */   

#fdw-pricing-table .plan {
    font: 13px 'Lucida Sans', 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;     
    background: #fff;      
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    _display: inline; /* IE6 double margin fix */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);      
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan:after {
  z-index: -1; 
  position: absolute; 
  content: "";
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 4px;
  width: 80%; 
  top: 80%; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 12px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);   
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 12px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 12px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);    
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);   
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);  
}   

#fdw-pricing-table .popular-plan {
    top: -20px;
    padding: 40px 20px;   
}

/* --------------- */   

#fdw-pricing-table .header {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: -20px -20px 20px -20px;
    border-bottom: 8px solid;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff,#eee);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#eee));    
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #eee);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #eee);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#fff, #eee);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #eee);
}

#fdw-pricing-table .header:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px; left: 0;
    height: 3px; width: 100%;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(images/bar.png);
}

#fdw-pricing-table .popular-plan .header {
    margin-top: -40px;
    padding-top: 60px;      
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan1 .header{
    border-bottom-color: #B3E03F;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan2 .header{
    border-bottom-color: #7BD553;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan3 .header{
    border-bottom-color: #3AD5A0;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan4 .header{
    border-bottom-color: #45D0DA;
}           

/* --------------- */

#fdw-pricing-table .price{
    font-size: 45px;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .monthly{
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999;
}

/* --------------- */

#fdw-pricing-table ul {
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#fdw-pricing-table li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

/* --------------- */

#fdw-pricing-table .signup {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;       
    background-color: #72ce3f;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;     
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    opacity: .9;       
}

#fdw-pricing-table .signup:hover {
    opacity: 1;       
}

#fdw-pricing-table .signup:active {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset;       
}           

#fdw-pricing-table .plan1 .signup{
    background: #B3E03F;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan2 .signup{
    background: #7BD553;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan3 .signup{
    background: #3AD5A0;
}

#fdw-pricing-table .plan4 .signup{
    background: #45D0DA;
}   

/* end --------------- */
```

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `margin: 0 5px;` in `#fdw-pricing-table .plan` selector.

Instead you can add bottom or top margin to have some space. Like so -

```
#fdw-pricing-table .plan {
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/u3f2ehse/1/)**

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting downvote on this. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I would upvote because your solution is simple and effective, but I'm a new user (need reps to upvote).

Comment: I'm not asking for upvote, I was wondering how I got two downvotes on this answer. And if the solution helps you to figure out the problem be sure mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: I just learned that the checkmark was even a button. I apologize for the newbiness. Thanks, again.

Comment: By accepting an answer you will get +2 reputation points. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! You can find one solution below.

http://jsfiddle.net/vjnLcce3/

Basically added CSS:

```
#fdw-pricing-table .spacer {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Then added `spacer` to the class of the second row of tables.

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought of that.